# SQL Percentage of True columns

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a table where each row has a description field as well as a boolean value. I'm trying to write a query where I can group by each respective description, and see the percentage of times that the boolean was true.

Example table:

```
    PID    Gender    SeniorCitizen
     1       M             1
     2       M             1
     3       F             0
     4       F             1
     5       M             0
```

And I want a query that will return this:

```
    Gender    SeniorPct
      M         .66
      F         .50
```

I've got to the point where I have a query that will calculate the individual percentages for a male or female - but I want to see both results at once

```
    SELECT Gender, COUNT(*) * 1.0 / 
                   (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM MyTable WHERE Gender='M') 
    FROM MyTable WHERE Gender='M' and SeniorCitizen=1;
```

I've been trying to include a "GROUP BY Gender" statement in my outer SELECT above, but I can't seem to figure out how to tweak the inner SELECT to get the correct results after tweaking the outer SELECT as such.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*(I tested this under MySQL, please check if the same idea can be applied to the SQLite.)*

To find the number of seniors (per gender), we can treat the bits as numbers and simply sum them up:

```
SELECT
    Gender,
    SUM(SeniorCitizen) Seniors
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY Gender

GENDER  SENIORS
M       2
F       1
```

Based on that, we can easily calculate percentages:

```
SELECT
    Gender,
    SUM(SeniorCitizen) / COUNT(*) * 100 SeniorsPct
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY Gender

GENDER  SENIORSPCT
M       66.6667
F       50
```

You can play with it in this [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7c6c2/8).

---

UPDATE: Very similar idea works under SQLite as well. Please take a look at another [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/d5f8f/3).

Comment: Nice answer. Simple and only scans the table once.

Comment: For MS T-SQL i get "Operate Data Type bit is Invalid for sum operator" when I try doing this against a Boolean (BIT) like in the original question here.

Comment: @CRSouser If `SeniorCitizen` is a `bit`, you'd need to cast it to `int` before summing: `SUM(CAST(SeniorCitizen AS int))`.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:

```
CREATE TABLE #MyTable
(
    PID INT,
    Gender VARCHAR(1),
    SeniorCitizen BIT
)

INSERT INTO #MyTable
(
    PID,
    Gender,
    SeniorCitizen
)
SELECT 1, 'M', 1 UNION
SELECT 2, 'M', 1 UNION
SELECT 3, 'F', 0 UNION
SELECT 4, 'F', 1 UNION
SELECT 5, 'M', 0

SELECT
    Gender,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN SeniorCitizen = 1 THEN 1 END), -- Count of SeniorCitizens grouped by Gender
    COUNT(1), -- Count of all users grouped by Gender
    CONVERT(DECIMAL(2, 2), -- You can ignore this if you want
        COUNT(CASE WHEN SeniorCitizen = 1 THEN 1 END) * 1.0 / COUNT(1) -- Your ratio
        )
FROM
    #MyTable
GROUP BY
    Gender
```